# OpenCV: declaring GPU matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

In OpenCV 2.4.3, I am trying to delcare one GPU matrix in this way:

```
cv::VideoCapture video;
video.open("sample.avi");
cv::Mat source;
for ( int n = 0; n < 500; n ++ )
{
    video >> source; 
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMat ( source );
}
```

Then I got the following error for the gpu matrix declaration:

```
Error: incomplete type is not allowed
```

What mistake did I make here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is associated with missing an include statement. Double check all the necessary includes are present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My included files are like this: #include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the API you could try including "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

Answer (score 0):

For opencv4, try this

```
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
```

fixed problem for me